# Date and Time in picker view in android for titanium

Tags: titanium, uicomponents

Here I need to generate the date and time picker for android in Titanium, 
The Titanium.UI.Picker is used for iphone only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think titanium does not support Date and Time Picker for android, only normal number picker are support.
Look [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Picker-object) (at the bottom).

Comment: use the property usespinner=true when allocating the picker