# Date on titanium

Tags: javascript, android, date, titanium

This question is a bit strange, sorry.

i read titanium doc abaout http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker

i also read the subject [Date and Time in picker view in android for titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656313/date-and-time-in-picker-view-in-android-for-titanium).

i wonder if titanium understand Date ?
i had to use it for 2 things : for a Date picker(working on android) & to manipulate Date .

however titanium draw a hugly bad alert when i try to use

```
date = new Date();
...
something(date.now());//alert here.
someotherthingorso(date.getTime());//alert here two if i delete the first.
```

so , what can we do with Date on titanium? only constructor & getter work for me.
is there a subsitute to date.now() or date.getTime() which is effective? also for datePicker.

Comment: Never used titanium but the linked documentation seems to indicate to use spinners with integer values for selection on Android, allowing you to make up a date from the individual components. It's not a date object but that just seems to be the way it is according to the docs.

Comment: Try `System.currentTimeInMilis()`

Comment: System is unknow on titanium :) . but well thinq. @@merlin

@@François Whal . understood , i may use it while there is no Date object implemented nor dateTime.(which look very strange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium fully supports the Date object, since it is a built-in JavaScript object. You are just using the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object incorrectly.

The `now()` method is available only on the actual Date object, you call it like this:

```
Date.now()
```

While the getTime() method is available only for `Date` instances:

```
var d = new Date();
d.getTime();
```